# Find all orthonormal bases of $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

The question is short:

''Find all orthonormal bases of $\mathbb{R^2}.$

**Recall**. A basis $\left\{v_1,...,v_n\right\}$ of $V$ is said to be orthogonal if its elements are mutually perpendicular. If in addition each element of the basis has norm $1$, then the basis is called *orthonormal.*

How can we find these? Can you help; can you give a hint?

Answer (score 2):

For $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, any unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be expressed as:

$$
u_1 = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)
$$

Can you find an orthonormal vector to $u_1$?

Comment: i couldn't find

Comment: Hint:  say the first component of the orthonormal vector is $\sin(\theta)$

Comment: @PozcuKushimotoStreet: Can you define what "orthonormal" means?

Comment: @Mefitico I wrote what it mean. Edited question.

Comment: Now, can you write down the condition for two vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$ to be perpendicular?

Comment: @Mefitico how can we write $u_2$? $u_2=(cos\theta', sin\theta')$?

Comment: Well, yes, that would be one example. You could use $\alpha$ instead of $\theta '$ to visualize better.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Define two vectors:$$v=[v_1\ \ v_2]\\u=[u_1\ \ u_2]$$and apply the orthogonality condition$$uv^T=v_1u_1+v_2u_2=0$$provided $v_1^2+v_2^2\ne 0$ and $u_1^2+u_2^2\ne 0$. What does it lead to? How many variables and how many equations to find them, remain there?

Comment: what is $v^T$ mean?

Comment: I mean the transpose of $v$...

Comment: what is transpose of a vector mean?

Comment: Generally, the transpose of an $m\times n$ matrix with entries being $a_{ij}$ is an $n\times m$ matrix whose entries are $a_{ji}$ e.g.$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\end{bmatrix}\implies\\A^T=\begin{bmatrix}1&4\\2&5\\3&6\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: thanks, I know this but you say that $v^T$, $v$ is a vector, and you say transpose of $v$, that is $v$ is a vector, not a matrix

Comment: In case of a vector, it is simply a conversion between a row and column vector i.e. $n\times 1$ and $1\times n$ vector. For example if $$v=[1\ \  2\ \  3]$$then$$v^T=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Ahh... yes.. thanks. And, I couldn't answer your questions: ''What does it lead to? How many variables and how many equations to find them, remain there?''. May you help more?

Comment: Sure. We have $4$ variables and an equation (not regarding the inequalities), leaving us with $3$ degrees of freedom. Now, take different scenarios (such as $v_1=0$, $u_1=0$, etc) to find out different branches of the solution.